# How to Create Certificate Signing Request on Windows 10 For Apple

Tags: ios, apple-developer, apple-developer-account, certificate-signing-request

Operating System of My Computer is Windows 10. And I am coding with React Native. 
I want to Create Certificate Signing Request for download Certificate in Apple Developer System . 
How can I create in Windows . I try to;

```
#openssl genrsa -out mykey.key 2018

#openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out myCSR.certSigningRequest -subj "/emailAddress=ublablavla@bla.com, CN=Umut, C=TR"
```

and when I want to upload to Apple Developer Account page , system give me a error ;

> Invalid Certificate

Comment: I was getting the same error even with mac. I think it is an Apple error. Try to reload the website and upload the certificate again and again. It works with me. Hopes it help.

Comment: @SidharthKhanna , I try about 20 times , error is same . Also I take a file from my friend which is using a mac , error is still same .

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem . Before I was using Edge Browser . But Now I am using Firefox Browser and I can upload the file .

Comment: Yes, as I said this is an Apple error. But it is not because of Browser. It might me because of cache.